# Reducing amount of primary partitions

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

Hello I'm trying to create room to install windows on a pre-installed Ubuntu 12.04 laptop. I'm using Gparted and currently my partitions look like this

[image]

Obviously I'm over 4 primary partitions and I'd like to know what/if I can move/change into extended partitions so I can free up room to convert my unallocated into a new primary partition.

I know I can delete the first one as that's my recovery partition from dell, but when I tried to create a recovery USB and CD I've been greeted with an error message so I'm worried if all goes wrong I won't get my factory settings back again.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following:

1. Back up all your important user data. The following steps pose a small risk of data loss.
2. In GParted, expand the extended partition to cover the available free space.
3. Shrink `/dev/sda2` by a tiny amount (1MiB should be sufficient).
4. Move `/dev/sda5` to the start of the freshly-expanded extended partition.
5. Type `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and check the type codes (under the `Id` column) of all your partitions.
6. Run my [FixParts program](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) and use it to convert `/dev/sda3` to logical form. If necessary, adjust the type codes of your partitions to match what `fdisk` showed. `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2` will probably have to be changed from 0x07 to 0x0c.
7. Re-launch GParted and, if necessary, shrink the extended partition so that the free space at the end of the disk lies outside of the extended partition.
8. Create a new primary partition for Windows at the end of the disk.

Alternatively, if the laptop is new enough (less than about 2 years old, give or take a bit), it probably has an [EFI/UEFI firmware.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uefi) If so, you could use `gdisk` to convert the disk from MBR to GPT format, install an [EFI boot loader for Linux,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders) and install Windows in EFI mode. This has the advantage that GPT supports up to 128 partitions by default, with no distinction between primary, extended, and logical partitions, so the partitioning task becomes easier; but EFI-mode booting is newer and still has glitches on some systems, so there's a greater risk of problems.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to know which approach is better without trying them both on your specific hardware. (Assuming of course that your firmware is EFI-based; if it's an older BIOS-only firmware, the second option isn't really available to you.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations i'll be back to it. It's a new inspirion 17R bought 2 days ago so i might have access to this EFI. I'm also very tempted to simply delete the first fat32 folder which from quick googling is " a diagnostic tool which has been made oudated by built-in BIOS diagnostic tool".

Comment: OK i've messed up something, even though i followed all the steps in the first option. This is what my gparted looks like when i tried to set the last free partition as ntfs:

step 8
http://i.imgur.com/mjBsUi7.png ,
which also has the pop up error message for ext 4.

This is the pop up message for "unknown" which was supposed to be the new NFTS partition
http://i.imgur.com/8mQNpBb.png

I'm worried i broke something bad, should i try to full reinstall with my recovery disc? Or is there another way of getting things normal?

Comment: Try running `partprobe`. If that fails, reboot the computer. As near as I can tell, the problem is simply that a partition was in use when you ran FixParts, with the result that the kernel kept using the old partition table. The `partprobe` utility usually overcomes this problem; and when it doesn't, rebooting always does.